# Converting a complex multidimensional array with named values to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array which I need to convert to JSON. My array, `classProfiles`, is structured as follows (copied and pasted from console output after typing the name of the array):

```
Buildings_clear: Array(0)
  band1: [Min: 24, Max: 24, Mean: 24, Median: 24, StdDev: 0]
  band2: [Min: 22, Max: 23, Mean: 22.5, Median: 22.5, StdDev: 0.5]
  band3: [Min: 18, Max: 19, Mean: 18.5, Median: 18.5, StdDev: 0.5]
  band4: [Min: 16, Max: 19, Mean: 17.5, Median: 17.5, StdDev: 1.5]
  band5: [Min: 18, Max: 23, Mean: 20.5, Median: 20.5, StdDev: 2.5]
  band6: [Min: 23, Max: 27, Mean: 25, Median: 25, StdDev: 2]
  band7: [Min: 25, Max: 30, Mean: 27.5, Median: 27.5, StdDev: 2.5]
  band8: [Min: 20, Max: 25, Mean: 22.5, Median: 22.5, StdDev: 2.5]
  band8a: [Min: 28, Max: 33, Mean: 30.5, Median: 30.5, StdDev: 2.5]
  band9: [Min: 8, Max: 8, Mean: 8, Median: 8, StdDev: 0]
  band10: [Min: 0, Max: 0, Mean: 0, Median: 0, StdDev: 0]
  band11: [Min: 28, Max: 34, Mean: 31, Median: 31, StdDev: 3]
  band12: [Min: 19, Max: 24, Mean: 21.5, Median: 21.5, StdDev: 2.5]
  length: 0
  __proto__: Array(0)
Grass_clear: Array(0)
  band1: [Min: 17, Max: 24, Mean: 18.61764705882353, Median: 17, StdDev: 2.70092256441423]
  band2: [Min: 13, Max: 21, Mean: 15.441176470588236, Median: 14, StdDev: 2.6030657996088817]
  band3: [Min: 13, Max: 19, Mean: 14.823529411764707, Median: 14, StdDev: 1.8225803982152553]
  band4: [Min: 10, Max: 22, Mean: 13.823529411764707, Median: 13, StdDev: 3.3560357236696263]
  band5: [Min: 18, Max: 24, Mean: 20.441176470588236, Median: 20, StdDev: 1.5183422940165066]
  band6: [Min: 22, Max: 48, Mean: 34, Median: 35, StdDev: 5.7650059945889955]
  band7: [Min: 24, Max: 58, Mean: 40.11764705882353, Median: 41, StdDev: 7.718445080692602]
  band8: [Min: 24, Max: 61, Mean: 41.14705882352941, Median: 42.5, StdDev: 8.398642582693581]
  band8a: [Min: 27, Max: 67, Mean: 46.588235294117645, Median: 48, StdDev: 9.003651700539992]
  band9: [Min: 7, Max: 19, Mean: 14.529411764705882, Median: 16, StdDev: 3.24703751058649]
  band10: [Min: 0, Max: 0, Mean: 0, Median: 0, StdDev: 0]
  band11: [Min: 29, Max: 50, Mean: 35.94117647058823, Median: 34, StdDev: 5.530350358386456]
  band12: [Min: 13, Max: 35, Mean: 19.08823529411765, Median: 17, StdDev: 6.084539941324887]
  length: 0
  __proto__: Array(0)
Soil_clear: Array(0)
  band1: [Min: 24, Max: 24, Mean: 24, Median: 24, StdDev: 0]
  band2: [Min: 26, Max: 28, Mean: 27, Median: 27, StdDev: 0.816496580927726]
  band3: [Min: 26, Max: 29, Mean: 27.666666666666668, Median: 28, StdDev: 1.247219128924647]
  band4: [Min: 29, Max: 35, Mean: 32.333333333333336, Median: 33, StdDev: 2.494438257849294]
  band5: [Min: 26, Max: 30, Mean: 28.333333333333332, Median: 29, StdDev: 1.699673171197595]
  band6: [Min: 30, Max: 35, Mean: 32.666666666666664, Median: 33, StdDev: 2.0548046676563256]
  band7: [Min: 33, Max: 38, Mean: 35.666666666666664, Median: 36, StdDev: 2.0548046676563256]
  band8: [Min: 36, Max: 43, Mean: 39.666666666666664, Median: 40, StdDev: 2.8674417556808756]
  band8a: [Min: 36, Max: 42, Mean: 39.333333333333336, Median: 40, StdDev: 2.494438257849294]
  band9: [Min: 8, Max: 8, Mean: 8, Median: 8, StdDev: 0]
  band10: [Min: 0, Max: 0, Mean: 0, Median: 0, StdDev: 0]
  band11: [Min: 37, Max: 42, Mean: 40.333333333333336, Median: 42, StdDev: 2.357022603955158]
  band12: [Min: 27, Max: 31, Mean: 29.666666666666668, Median: 31, StdDev: 1.8856180831641267]
  length: 0
  __proto__: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Typing `typeof classProfiles` in the console gives me `"object"`.

If I try this:

```
var classProfilesJSON = JSON.stringify(classProfiles)
```

... then `classProfilesJSON` prints in the console as `"[]"`.

So I tried using jQuery to turn the array into an object first:

```
var classProfilesObject = $.extend({},classProfiles)
var classProfilesJSON = JSON.stringify(classProfilesObject)
```

... which resulted in `ClassProfilesJSON` looking like this:

```
"{\"Grass_clear\":[],\"Buildings_clear\":[],\"Soil_clear\":[]}"
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I convert this array into complete and usable JSON, keeping all of the names/keys and values intact?

Comment: Arrays will not serialise those properties to JSON they should be objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having this same difficulty, the solution for me began with adjusting how I was declaring/creating these arrays, and setting them up as objects instead:

In relevant parts of my code where I was creating arrays like this...

```
var classProfiles = [];
```

... I needed to change these lines to be like this, so that I was creating objects instead of arrays:

```
var classProfiles = {};
```

And then (after a few other adjustments in other parts of my code relating to how using objects is different to using arrays) it was possible to serialise my objects (not arrays) into JSON.